# AngularJS + PHP contact form, POST 405 (Not Allowed)

Tags: php, angularjs, nginx

I get POST 405 (Not Allowed) in the console whenever I try to send a message through a contact form.

App.js

```
$scope.submitData = function() {
   $http({
   url: 'handle.php',
   method: 'POST',
   data: {"name": $scope.name,"email": $scope.email,"message": $scope.message},
   headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
   })
   .success(function() {
     window.alert("Success");
   })
   .error(function() {
     window.alert("Failure");
   })
}
```

Handle.php

```
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$name = $data['name'];
$email = $data['email'];
$message = $data['message'];

//to, subject, message, headers, parameters.
mail($to, $name, $email, $message);
?>
```

Contact.html

```
<form action="" method="post" ng-submit="submitData()" ng-controller="contactController">
<p>name:</p>
<input name="name" type="text" ng-model="name">
<p>email:</p>
<input name="email" type="text" ng-model="email">
<p>message:</p>
<textarea name="message" type="text" cols="40" rows="5" ng-model="message"></textarea>
<p><div id="html_element"></div><p>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I'm running a nginx web server on raspberry pi.

Is the handle.php correct?

I assume that this error means that something is not configured on the server? What do I need to configure?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install a plugin to make ajax call to other servers. Try download this and may it help:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

After install, click the plugin, add and url:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns 
and then try again.